# Define a type constraint with abstract type

Tags: scala, type-systems

I try to define a type constraint with abstract type. but unfortunately, it doesn't compile.

```
  sealed trait MatchableValue {
    type A
    def value: A

    def asSingleItemValue : ItemValue
  }

  sealed trait ItemValue {
    type A
    def value: A
  }

  case class StringValue(value: String) extends ItemValue {type A = String}
  case class StringMatchableValue(value: String) extends MatchableValue{
    type A = String
    override def asSingleItemValue =  StringValue(value)
  }
```

Unfortunately, this one doesn't work

```
def asSingleItemValue[B <: ItemValue](implicit ev: A =:= B#A) : B
```

The aim of the type constraint is to be warned at compile-time of such an error :

```
  case class IntValue(value: Int) extends ItemValue {type A = Int}
  case class IntMatchableValue(value: Int) extends MatchableValue{
    type A = Int
    def asSingleItemValue = StringValue("error")
  }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're aiming for. When you have an abstract generic method in the base trait, that means the caller gets to pick the type parameters, which means the implementation in the subclass also needs to be generic.

Comment: Check at compile time the dependencies between type. i.e. that prevent from type errors like that : case class StringMatchableValue(value: String) extends MatchableValue{override def asSingleItemValue =  BooleanValue(value)}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can accomplish this with a type refinement (note the method's return type):

```
sealed trait MatchableValue { self =>
  type A
  def value: A

  def asSingleItemValue: ItemValue { type A = self.A }
}

sealed trait ItemValue {
  type A
  def value: A
}

case class StringValue(value: String) extends ItemValue { type A = String }
case class IntValue(value: Int) extends ItemValue { type A = Int }
```

Now this compiles:

```
case class StringMatchableValue(value: String) extends MatchableValue {
  type A = String
  def asSingleItemValue = StringValue(value)
}
```

But this doesn't:

```
case class StringMatchableValue(value: String) extends MatchableValue {
  type A = String
  def asSingleItemValue = IntValue(1)
}
```

Which I believe is what you want.

---

It's also worth noting that the following is a common pattern when dealing with type refinements:

```
sealed trait MatchableValue { self =>
  type A
  def value: A

  def asSingleItemValue: ItemValue.Aux[A]
}

sealed trait ItemValue {
  type A
  def value: A
}

object ItemValue {
  type Aux[A0] = ItemValue { type A = A0 }
}
```

This does exactly the same thing, but the syntax is a nice alternative if you find yourself needing to write out the type refinement a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to delete this line in your code?

```
def asSingleItemValue = StringValue(value)
```

and the `override` definition has some of the signature missing and should be like this:

```
override def asSingleItemValue[B <: ItemValue](implicit ev: =:=[String, B#A]): B = ev
```

Finally, the resulting type of `ev` needs to be `B`.

Comment: This is correct but it doesn't really answer the question (which was admittedly not very clear before the edit).